# How to customize Ninja log output with CMake? (Possible?)

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, ninja

When I'm compiling with *Makefile* build log is colorful and detailed. But when I use *Ninja* I'm getting only one line with progress, without percentage and color. How can I make *Ninja* build log look like *Makefile*'s one? Is this even possible or that must require *Ninja* developers actions?

Example:

Makefile log:

[image]

Ninja log:

[image]

PS any method welcome, will be used locally.

PPS if there is no one, just say that this is impossible for now.

Comment: @user4581301: Here the image is OK because the question is about **colorful** logs and the image provides an *example* of such log.

Comment: Good point. I fixated on the one line part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Following the [Ninja documentation](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html), you can customize the progress status by setting the `NINJA_STATUS` environment variable with several placeholders.

In your case, to print the percentage you have to set this variable before running ninja (assuming you are running ninja on a unix environment):

```
export NINJA_STATUS="[%p ] "

cmake -GNinja ..
ninja
```

Comment: Percentage is what I like, however that's only part of the problem. Mist importantly I want it to not override previous line. Adding \n inside status variable does not really help, \\n does not work too...